# Geolocation error, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: c#, android, class, xamarin, gps

I am working on a Xamarin Cross Platform App and I have a problem when I try to obtain my gps coords. I have this code to get the gps information:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        position = await GetPosition();

        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
    }

    async Task<Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position> GetPosition()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        return position;
    }
```

When it reaches the line:

```
Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

It gives me this exception:

> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "md57251f317a80041e1a60080af127573bd.GeolocationSingleListener" on
>   path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.companyname.PruebaMapas-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.PruebaMapas-1/lib/x86,
>   /system/fake-libs,
>   /data/app/com.companyname.PruebaMapas-1/base.apk!/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

I don't know why. I add the "Plugin.Geolocator" using NuGet and it is on my PruebaMapas project and on my PruebaMapas.Android project too.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please read and ensure you followed the official documentation of this plugin: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html

Comment: I follow all the instructions and it still gives me that exception

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: No, what is it?

Comment: It looks like it is missing a class, isn't it?

Comment: See https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_8/xamarin.android_8.1/#Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did your application works without using GeoPlugin ? If not it can be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812966/xamarin-custom-view-classnotfoundexception/47813126#47813126) so u can try this solution. This is known issue in Xamarin android 8.1.

Comment: BTW there is a VS extension to delete the bin & obj directories via build menu: https://github.com/yuv4ik/vsmacdeepclean

Comment: Is there any similiar extension for windows?

Comment: Seems like there at least one : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EmmanuelKrebs.DeepClean

Comment: Glad i can help :)